# create pandas dataframe, then update only last day/row without calling (ie omitting) the first part of the function - all in one statement

Tags: python, pandas, date

As the title suggests, I'm not even sure how to word the question. :D

But here it is, "simply put":
I) I would like to create a df on day x and II) from the next day onwards x+1...x+n I would like to update just day x+n without touching the first part (I) of creating the df - and all that by only calling one function. So basically "just" appending the row for the day the function is called (there is no need to "recreate" the df since it is already there. Is there a possibility to do that all in one statement?

It would look something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def pull_data():

    data = {'DATE': ['2020-05-01','2020-05-02','2020-05-03','2020-05-04'],
            'X': [400,300,200,100],
            'Y': [100,200,300,400]
            }

    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['DATE', 'X', 'Y'])

    return df

data_ = pull_data()
```

Let's say I call this function on 2020-05-04 --> but now on the next day I want it to automatically ONLY attach 2020-05-05 without creating the whole data frame again.

Does my whole question make any sense/is it comprehensible? I'd be happy about every input! :)

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear, are you saying you want to persist the same dataframe in memory from day to day, within the scope of the same function, and not write it to a file or database or indeed exit or rerun the function? This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Yes, I know, I'm sorry.

So on day 1 I download the data and transform it into a df, on all the ensuing days (2...n), I only want to add the rows of those days without redoing part I -- but all by calling the same function. So basically on day 2 and 3 and 4, I run the script and it only appends one row at the end of the df.

Well yes, it is written to a file but on the next day that file should just be updated with the last day.

Comment: so the data will need to be saved somewhere between executions of the script

Comment: Yes, it is saved between the executions. The thing is that I want to run script A to create the df and on the next day run script A again to append the rows (it is meant to run as a dag)

Comment: In your function definition, you can have an argument that, if set to `None`, creates a dataframe. But if you instead pass in a dataframe to that arg, then have it append to the passed dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the dataframe and the integer index, you can append a value using the shape of the dataframe with `loc`:

```
from datetime import datetime

data_ = pull_data()
value_X = 0
value_Y = 1
data_.loc[data_.shape[0]] = [datetime.now().date(), value_X, value_Y]

data_

#   DATE    X   Y
# 0 2020-05-01  400 100
# 1 2020-05-02  300 200
# 2 2020-05-03  200 300
# 3 2020-05-04  100 400
# 4 2020-05-06  0   1
```